# How to add a comma to payload message?

Tags: javascript, node-red

This may be an easy problem to fix in node red.

I receive a payload from my temperature sensor: 230 and i need to change it to 23.0

How can I in node red add a comma so the value changes from 230 to 23,0

Kind regards

Comment: Divide by ten? Anyway, without seeing your code and your inputs it may be a bit hard to answer.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!!